# Why MongoDB is not using hash join or sort merge?

Tags: mongodb

Why MongoDB does not use hash join or sort merge to enhance query performance?

Thanks

Comment: Because it is not a relational database?

Comment: MongoDB supports joints in there lookup. But performance will be very bad if it rely on full scans.

Comment: That's where an indexing strategy helps.

Comment: Yes, but this is not avilable in MongoDB.

Comment: The simple form of lookup, and the pipeline form if the first stage is equality matches, do support using an index.

Answer (score 0):

Mongodb implemented a (almost) useless feature ($lookup) to fire the SQL vs NoSQL conversation.

The lookup operator performance is way worse than a SQL join. They knew nobody is going to use it. Why optimise a useless feature with merge and hash joins.

It's like a marketing gimmick, buy this car and get a cleaning shampoo free. It's suppose to make Mongodb look good in front of other NoSQL databases.

The bottomline is $lookup is as good as a application level join. You should not use it. If you are feeling the need:

- The problem might be your data Model. Fixing it might eliminate the need. (Embedded documents)
- But if you really need it, then SQL might be the way forward.

https://www.enterprisedb.com/blog/comparison-joins-mongodb-vs-postgresql

https://medium.com/@liams_o/lookup-in-mongodb-if-you-are-using-it-something-is-wrong-45d3fd47ac61